# Cannot install PS3 Media Server on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, package-management, software-installation, mediaserver, ps3

I cannot install the PS3 Media Server onto Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I try to run the recommended commands I get the following error message.

```
"The following packages have unmet dependencies: ps3mediaserver : Depends : ps3mediaserver-multiarch but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
```

The commands I used are:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:happy-neko/ps3mediaserver

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ps3mediaserver
```

I do not know what the "ps3mediaserver-multiarch" part is about at all. I have searched high and low but no one seems to really know. I have even posted on other Ubuntu support sites. No one seems to know on the other sites. Does anyone have any ideas on a way to get PS3 Media Server installed on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? O_o Any feed back is much appreciated.

Just a heads up, I have installed mencoder, ffmpeg and other transcoding tools like VLC, ect. This did not assist in solving the issue.

I have tried user278794's solution from another thread but that does not work either.

Their commands were as follows.

```
 sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

paste this

```
 deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/happy-neko/ps3mediaserver/ubuntu raring main
 deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/happy-neko/ps3mediaserver/ubuntu raring main
```

exit.

```
 sudo apt-get install ps3mediaserver
```

The first sudo command goes right. But when I try to paste the next lines into the editing window it will not save them. When I try to save/exit it gives off this message.

```
 "Could not find the file "/etc/apt/sources.list". Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again."
```

Am I doing something wrong with those commands?

I am rather new to Linux Ubuntu so I am not sure. As the software package is not available in the software center this is rather frustrating.  Again, any feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I followed the solution listed here: http://adam.pohorecki.pl/blog/2014/05/16/how-to-install-ps3-media-server-on-ubuntu-14-dot-04-trusty-tahr/

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:happy-neko/ps3mediaserver
sudo sed -i s/trusty/raring/ /etc/apt/sources.list.d/happy-neko-ps3mediaserver-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ps3mediaserver
```

Worked great for me!

Comment: sadly the apt-get update step comes back with a 404 on the ps3mediaserver

Answer (score 1):

The happy-neko PPA offers nothing for the Trusty distro.

noobslab/apps is a PPA with updated packages : http://www.noobslab.com/2014/01/ps3-media-server-for-ubuntulinux.html

BUT, there is a problem with the NoobsLab PPA for the PS3 Media Server. At present, the noobslab PPA does not include the dependency ps3mediaserver-multiarch (see comments in link above).

Hopefully that will get fixed soon and then you should be able to install ps3mediaserver from the noobslab/apps PPA in Ubuntu 14.04 using the simple commands in the article linked above.

In the meantime, you can do the following to work around the issue.

First, add the noobslab ppa and update packages:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, add the happy-neko PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:happy-neko/ps3mediaserver
```

Happy-Neko doesn't offer anything for trusty currently, so no point in updating. Now you will edit the PPA you just added in order to gain access to the most recent version of that missing packet. Open "Software & Updates" and select the "Other Software" tab. Scroll down to the happy-nekok ppa you added and select it. Then choose "Edit" at the bottom of the window. In the "Distribution" line, delete "trusty" and type "raring". Hit "OK" and exit "Software & Updates"--doing so should also prompt a fresh scan of available packages.

Now, you are going to install that package missing from the noobslab ppa:

```
sudo apt-get install ps3mediaserver-multiarch
```

Now that the missing dependency is installed. You should have success in installing the PS3 Media Server from the NoobsLab PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install ps3mediaserver
```

Note: I had to install several other dependencies in order to get this to work, but they were already existing in the regular Ubuntu software sources.

If the NoobsLab PPA is updated to include the ps3mediaserver-multiarch package in the future that new trusty distribution of the package should supersede this raring distribution. At that time you can just remove the Happy-Neko PPA as it would no longer be providing you any packages.

Comment: One more note. Be aware that running "update" after installing the NoobsLab PPA will upgrade a bunch of the official Ubuntu packages. If you want to remove the PPA, tt may be best to run ppa-purge prior to doing so--this will revert those PPA-upgraded packages back to the official Ubuntu packages.

Comment: Just FYI **ppa:noobslab/apps** is fully working now. No need to add **ppa:happy-neko/ps3mediaserver**